# how to put one gridlayout on top of the other?

Tags: android, eclipse, keyboard, grid-layout

I designed two keyboard and I added a button that, when clicked, will switch between these keyboards.

I want to place these two keyboard on top of each other when i am designing so the user can click and the first keyboard will disappear the second pops up. The problem I'm having is that cannot figure out how to put them on the same place using a `GridLayout`.

A second problem I'm having is changing the background of the `GridLayout`.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final  GridLayout kb2s = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.kb2);
    final  GridLayout kb1s = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.kb1);
    kb1s.setBackgroundColor(128);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about wrap both keyboards with FrameLayout?

you can put the first keyboard FrameLayout  and when the switch button was click put the second keyboard to FrameLayout and when the switch button was click again remove the second keyboard from the FrameLayout

for the document look at this [FrameLayout Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)